# Use gitlab environment(or branch) name in sources

Tags: gitlab-ci

Good day, all.

In serverless framework 'serverless.yml' i have a database variable.

```
  environment:
    DATABASE_NAME: ${'test-db'}
```

In Gitlab CI I try to replace the same database name with branch or environment name in serverless.yml file. `serverless deploy` command uses serverless.yml content to deploy resources.
i tried:

```
DATABASE_NAME: ${ CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME }
DATABASE_NAME: ${ $CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME }
```

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: ~some-nodejs-image

stages:
  - deploy

deploy_development:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - serverless deploy -v
  environment: 
    name: development
  only:
    - develop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are conflating bash syntax, with the variable syntax allowed in serverless.yml.

Try:

```
DATABASE_NAME: ${env:CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}
```

Comment: Yes, it works.
I think i tried another variant DATABASE_NAME: ${env:$CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}
It is a frustating question.